# Knowing / defining sensing year from data to extract using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, forest-ecology

I extracted pixel values at given points in the Google Earth Engine from the vegetation cover data set **MOD44B.006**:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_006_MOD44B#description

That is the code I used:

```
// Load Data 
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD44B');

var visualization = {
  bands: ['Percent_Tree_Cover'],
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  palette: ['bbe029', '0a9501', '074b03']
};

Map.centerObject(dataset);

Map.addLayer(dataset, visualization, 'Percent Tree Cover');

var image = dataset.first();

// Extracting values 
var sampled_points = image.sampleRegions({ 
  collection: points, 
  scale: 30, // pixel resolution in meters 
  geometries: true // if ‘true’, the point coordinates will be added to the output
});

print(sampled_points, 'Percent_Tree_Cover');

// Drawing chart to download CSV values 
print(ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({ 
  features: sampled_points, 
  yProperties: ['Percent_Tree_Cover']
}));

Map.centerObject(sampled_points, 3); 
Map.addLayer(sampled_points, {color: 'blue'}, 'sampled');

// Exporting features, specifying corresponding names 
Export.table.toDrive(sampled_points, 
"sampled_points", //my task
"GEE_Folder", //my export folder in Google Drive 
"vegetation_cover", //file name 
"CSV");
```

On the GEE Website (link above) it says, that the data has an availability from **2000-03-05T00:00:00Z – 2020-03-05T00:00:00**.

How do I know from what sensing period within these 20 years my extraced data is and how can I define in the code, from what time period or year I want it to extract the pixel values at my points?

I need the most current I can get.

I am pretty new to GEE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter your entire MODIS image collection modifying the following line:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD44B')
                .filterDate('2000-03-05', '2000-10-05');
```

The `ee.ImageCollection.filterDate` function allows to filter the image collection by a date range.

Then you can print your MODIS image collection using:

```
print(dataset)
```

and explore the properties of your images. One of these properties will contain the date of acquisition or date of composition. I believe in your collection it is in the `date_range` property, in UnixTime.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ec5501c02d31f49c46cd06a15ec60a83